# (elisp) emacs 上でパスワードをクエリするには？

Tags: elisp

emacs 上で、パスワードをクエリしたいと考えています。

イメージとしては、ミニバッファでクエリが表示され、タイプした文字が * などで非表示になりながら入力し、ENTER を押したら、その入力文字が string で取得できるような、query-password のような関数が欲しいのですが、これはどうやったら実現できるでしょうか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

emacs のバージョンはいくつでしょう？とりあえずぱっと探してみたら

emacs-20.7 は comint.el に comint-read-noecho があった
emacs-22.3 は subr.el に read-passwd とか comint.el に send-invisible とかあった
emacs-23.3 は 22.3 と同じ

このへんのどれかが使えると思うです。